# Undefined map occurs on cluster

Tags: hazelcast, hazelcast-imap

When I run my application with hazelcast and check distributed object on the application or on man-center I saw a strange map(c95b3d56...) even I did not create or pre-defined map.

[image: strange cache]

Is there any advice what it could be and for what.

Below configuration is used in the application and no programmatic config.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<hazelcast xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.hazelcast.com/schema/config hazelcast-config-3.8.xsd" xmlns="http://www.hazelcast.com/schema/config" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
................
<map name="stressCache">
    <in-memory-format>BINARY</in-memory-format>
    <backup-count>0</backup-count>
    <statistics-enabled>false</statistics-enabled>
    <async-backup-count>0</async-backup-count>
    <time-to-live-seconds>10</time-to-live-seconds>
    <max-idle-seconds>0</max-idle-seconds>
    <eviction-policy>NONE</eviction-policy>
    <eviction-percentage>25</eviction-percentage>
    <min-eviction-check-millis>100</min-eviction-check-millis>
    <merge-policy>com.hazelcast.map.merge.PutIfAbsentMapMergePolicy</merge-policy>
</map>
```

Comment: Can you please share your Hazelcast cluster configuration, including the programmatic ones if any?

Comment: @AlparslanAvci thanks for the response. I have added the whole config.

Comment: If it's any help, "c95b3d56-2045-4fad-831e-34d0480021b9" is the string representation of a UUID.

Answer (score 0):

Hazelcast doesn't create any distributed maps internally. Also, the map you mentioned isn't seen in your configuration. This means it should be created by calling `HazelcastInstance#getMap()` API. Please check it if it is called in any part of your code, including the libraries that you are using.

Comment: Thank for the answer. I will check.

Comment: Try adding a [DistributedObjectListener](https://docs.hazelcast.org/docs/3.11/javadoc/com/hazelcast/core/DistributedObjectListener.html). This will alert you to exactly when the map is created. Not why or where, but it will help localise.